# FactoryGirl and Rails 3.2 error

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, factory-bot

I have this in factories.rb:

```
FactoryGirl.create :user do |user|
  user.name "test"
  user.age "40"
end
```

and this in my test file:

```
require 'spec_helper'

describe "FirstTests" do
    it "creates a user" do
     user=Factory(:user)
    end
end
```

Like always nothing works. Could somebody explain me why I am getting this?

```
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/factory_girl-4.1.0/lib/factory_girl/registry.rb:24:in `find': Factory not registered: user (ArgumentError)
```

Everything is there. why I am getting this error?

Comment: That syntax is outdated, try like this: `user = FactoryGirl.build(:user)`

Answer (score 5):

You are using `create` instead of `define`

```
FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :user do
    name "test"
    age "40"
  end
end
```

and `Factory(:user)` instead of `FactoryGirl.create(:user)`, or more simply `create(:user)`

https://github.com/thoughtbot/factory_girl/wiki/Usage

Comment: @TestTest Typo'd it. Sorry. Updated answer. Check the wiki page I linked to for usage